# Roman Numerals Kata in C

Tags: c

Here is a "Roman Numerals" kata implementation. Given a decimal number one has to return a corresponding roman number.

I have following questions:

1. Is memory management correct? Here I assume that the caller is responsible for freeing memory.
2. Does this code conform to `c` code style?
3. Does it look like idiomatic `c`?

Thanks!

`toRoman.h`:

```
char * toRoman(int n);

typedef struct DecimalToRoman {
    int decimal;
    const char * roman;
} DecimalToRoman;
```

`toRoman.c`:

```
char * toRoman(int n) {
    if (n < 1) return NULL;

    const DecimalToRoman numbers[] = {
        { 1000, "M"  },
        {  900, "CM" },
        {  500, "D"  },
        {  400, "CD" },
        {  100, "C"  },
        {   90, "XC" },
        {   50, "L"  },
        {   40, "XL" },
        {   10, "X"  },
        {    9, "IX" },
        {    5, "V"  },
        {    4, "IV" },
        {    1, "I"  }
    };

    size_t resultLen = 1;
    int tmp = n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof numbers / sizeof(DecimalToRoman) && tmp; i++) {
        while(tmp >= numbers[i].decimal) {
            tmp -= numbers[i].decimal;
            resultLen += strlen(numbers[i].roman);
        }
    }

    char * result = malloc(resultLen);
    if (result == NULL) {
        perror("allocate");
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(result, '\0', resultLen);

    for (size_t i = 0, r = 0; r < sizeof numbers / sizeof(DecimalToRoman); r++) {
        while (n >= numbers[r].decimal) {
            n -= numbers[r].decimal;

            int j = 0;
            while (numbers[r].roman[j])
                result[i++] = numbers[r].roman[j++];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: By "Roman Numerals", do you mean https://www.codewars.com/kata/51b62bf6a9c58071c600001b/c? Or did you try to solve the problem in general? Is the header part of Codewars provided code or your own?

Comment: Yes, this is the kata. But I was practicing it here https://cyber-dojo.org/

Answer (score 3):

```
toRoman.h
```

Is there any reason to expose `DecimalToRoman` to callers?

---

```
char * toRoman(int n)
```

Nit: it might be preferable to take `unsigned` rather than `int` as you cannot really handle negative numbers.

---

```
if (n < 1) return NULL;
```

Seems reasonable.  If you took unsigned, then you would only have to handle 0.  In that case, it might make sense to return `""` so you always return a valid string.

On second thought, there's sort of an upper-bound on what you can reasonably write as a roman numeral.  Does it make sense to write two billion in terms of thousands?  If you choose an upper bound, you can make assumptions about the length of your buffer.

---

```
const DecimalToRoman numbers[] = {
....
```

I love that this is written out so clearly.  Nice.

---

```
size_t resultLen = 1;
```

Help a reader out by saying why you init to 1.  IMO it's not obvious until you get to malloc.

```
int tmp = n;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof numbers / sizeof(DecimalToRoman) && tmp; i++) {
    while(tmp >= numbers[i].decimal) {
        tmp -= numbers[i].decimal;
        resultLen += strlen(numbers[i].roman);
    }
}
```

How about making this a function?  There's a common pattern:

```
Type thing = init;
...actually figure out what thing is often with a loop...

// don't change thing anymore!
... use thing ...
```

This is almost always more clearly written as:

```
Type const thing = createThing(init);
... use thing ...
```

But anyway back to this code.

```
sizeof numbers / sizeof(DecimalToRoman)
```

How about making this a variable named `lenNumbers` or something like that?  Super nit: I like that you used parens for the type and not for the expression, but IMO it looks weird with the operator/.  More clear: `(sizeof numbers) / sizeof(DecimalToRoman)`.

---

```
if (result == NULL) {
    perror("allocate");
    return NULL;
}
```

Good.  I admit I usually `assert` in situations like this since there's not much you can do when you're out of memory (and it rarely happens in the things I do), but this is the party line.

---

```
memset(result, '\0', resultLen);
```

Isn't this overkill?  You're about to overwrite the memory anyway.  Could just set the last character to '\0` (and you might as well do that after you write the answer for cache locality).

---

```
        int j = 0;
        while (numbers[r].roman[j])
            result[i++] = numbers[r].roman[j++];
```

Better option: a `for` loop.  Best option: `strcpy`.

---

You could remove the calls to strlen by storing the length in `DecimalToRoman`.  The lengths are tiny so this is more a question of simplicity than optimization.

---

There's a common pattern in C APIs for returning buffers. The idea is you let the user pass in the buffer and you return an error code.  Something like:

```
int getRomanNumerals(int nInput, char* strOut, int* nLen);
```

The return value is either success, failure, or "insufficient buffer" (you probably want an enum or a preprocessor `#define` for this).  In any case, the user passes in a buffer and the buffer's length.  You always set `nLen` to the number of bytes needed, and you set `strOut` if you have enough space (maybe you start setting `strOut` assuming the buffer is long enough, but stop writing if you run out of space and only need to set `nLen`).

This way the user can do crazy stuff like store the result in a weird place or maybe the user knows they don't have enough memory to store the whole thing etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Is memory management correct? Here I assume that the caller is responsible for freeing memory.

Yes. The allocated size needed is correct.  Proper `NULL` allocation test done.

> Does this code conform to c code style?

`DecimalToRoman;` in .h unnecessarily exposes implementation.  Format looks similar to the C spec.

> Does it look like idiomatic c?

Not as much as it could.  .h file lacks any indication that the caller needs to free anything.  Consider that the .c file is opaque to the user.  A return value of `NULL` is a surprise.  Function name does not hint at allocation.  The .h lacks useful info to understated the function.

I see C moving more toward the caller supplying the buffer and size for such helper function.  Also with size leading the pointer.

---

3 ideas: together to form a nifty result:

1. Consider passing in the destination buffer and its size and use `unsigned`.

   ```
   char * toRoman(size_t sz, char *dest, unsigned n);
   ```
2. Roman numbers did employ `()` or the like for [large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers). `"N"` is is reasonable result for 0.

   ```
   5000 --> "(V)"
   0 --> "N"
   ```
3. Using #2, then for a given `UINT_MAX`, there is a small, pre-determinate max size needed.

Now the `resultLen` pre-calculation is not needed.  Just use a temp buffer of the max size and copy.  This `ROMAN_SZ` belongs in the .h file so a caller may benefit knowing the max size.

```
#if UINT_MAX == ‭42949672965u
  #define ROMAN_SZ 52  /* (((III)))((DCCCLXXXVIII))(DCCCLXXXVIII)DCCCLXXXVIII */

#else if ...
```

---

Putting this together

```
char * toRoman(char *dest, size_t, sz, unsigned n) {
  char tmp[ROMAN_SZ];

  // Fill tmp based on `n`, no worry about overrun.

  size_t needed = strlen(tmp) + 1;
  if (needed > sz) {
    Handle_error();  // could use NULL or "" to indicate error
  } else {
    return strcpy(dest, tmp);
  }
```

Now the fun part, use a macro and *compound literal*  for an `malloc()`-less `TO_ROMAN()`

```
 #define TO_ROMAN(u) toRoman(ROMAN_SZ, (char [ROMAN_SZ]){""}, (u))
```

Code can use `TO_ROMAN()` to form a *string* that is valid to the end of the block with no `*alloc(), free()` needed.

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%s %s\n", TO_ROMAN(42), TO_ROMAN(12345));
}
```

This is akin to [printing in any base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641674/2410359)

Comment: Functions that are passed a buffer and size can be more useful if they return a count of the number of characters produced - or which would be produced, if greater than size.  Then callers can dynamically allocate and re-call if necessary.  Also useful if `NULL, 0` is accepted for this case.  `snprintf()` is a good model here.

Comment: @toby Good ideas.  Yet with `toRoman()`, it makes sense that common usage would employ buffer size `ROMAN_SZ` and use `strlen()` after calling `toRoman()`  if the string length was really needed.